# Adding column while loading csv in SQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, csv

I have an existing table (NameList) in to which I would like to load the contents of multiple csv files (fileA.csv, fileB.csv ...). The columns of the table are identical to those of the csv except that I want to record for each row the id of the csv file it came from. The id would be taken from another table which contains the properties of each file.

The table with the list of files would look like this:

```
CREATE TABLE files
(
id serial,
fileName varchar(128),
path varchar(256),
PRIMARY KEY (id)
)
```

The table to insert the csv contents in to would look like:

```
CREATE TABLE NameList
(
FirstName varchar(40),
LastName varchar(40),
SourceFile_ID int,
FOREIGN KEY (SourceFile_ID) REFERENCES files(id)
)
```

The csv files would look as follows:

```
Name of file:
fileA.csv

Contents:
FirstName,LastName
John,Smith
.
.
.
```

The only thing relating to this I could find so far is this:
[Add extra column while importing csv data in table in SQL server table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63590209/add-extra-column-while-importing-csv-data-in-table-in-sql-server-table)
However they suggest to use a default value on the additional column which would not solve my problem since I need to have a different value for each file I add.

Comment: You can import the csv and then update the id column

Comment: Hi @Marko how can I update only the rows that I just imported without touching the ones that are already in the table?

Comment: You only need to update those records that have the default value...

Comment: @Luuk Interesting, would this be considered good practice though? Would this not create a problem if for instance 2 csv's get added at the same time. Both would have default value associated with them so when I update based on default value a mistake would happen.

Also this would involve an extra lookup on every insert which would probably not be so efficient on this table as it's very large.

Comment: @sev you could insert the data into a temporary table (https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-temporary-table/), update the column, then move the data to the main table. This would avoid problems with 2 CSVs being loaded at once, because they'd be using different  temp tables (as long as 2 different db sessions are used for the inserts). Even if only one connection is used, you could have different names for the temp table for different CSVs.

Comment: @Marko temporary tables seems to be a good lead - I'll try that out. If you'd like you can write it up as an answer so I can accept it.

Comment: @sev: You are right, but I did not know your where busy importing files all day. In the situation where I am confronted with importing CSV data, this is always only one file import at a time... 

Comment: @Luuk haha yes no doubt my process will need to be updated to become more efficient but for now I need to load a couple of 1000s of csv's per day

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could insert the data into a temporary table (https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-temporary-table), update the column, then move the data to the main table.

This would avoid problems with 2 CSVs being loaded at once, because they'd be using different temp tables (as long as 2 different db sessions are used for the inserts). Even if only one session is used, you could have different names for the temp table for different CSVs.